# asp.net postback with jquery ajax and jquery dialog

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui, postback

We have a method on an asp.net page that is called on a button click. The problem is that the method take a long time to process. I've been asked to have the page call the method (or call the postback) and then display the jquery.ui dialog which will let the user know that this process could take a long time. I'm looking at serializing the asp.net form and doing a $.post() but to be honest I'm completely stuck on whether this will even work and how I can prevent the actual postback from happening and just displaying the dialog. Has anyone had any experience with doing this that can give me some pointers?

I found this http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/eliminating-postbacks-setting- but I'm not sure if it's a bit OTT. The article is a little long winded.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Hi:

Can you post your javascript bit up here so that we can have a look at it? Normally I would use the explicitly $.ajax() method because it is more flexible. And, the process on the server side might really take up to a long time to finish so improving only on the client side might not be efficient.

Answer (score 1):

That would be easier if you can use an UpdatePanel (which basically boils down to ASP.NET's way of doing what you're considering with the $.post(), but automatically gets the ASP.NET specific stuff right).

Then, you can do something simple like this:  http://encosia.com/2008/10/04/using-jquery-to-enhance-aspnet-ajax-progress-indication/

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use an Update panel. This is an existing application in Delphi.net and doesn't have the MS Ajax included. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can send a post request through javascript (AJAX) without using asp.net's ajax framework. So in other words do it manually. Ajax would be perfect in this case, because you are trying to show loading indicators on the front-end while you are waiting for a response from the server.

To do this, take the logic out of your button_click method and put it in a separate page (text.aspx see below). Then you can call that page like this (using JQuery):

```
$('#ProgressIndicator').show();
$.post("test.aspx", function(data){
  alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
  $('#ProgressIndicator').hide();
});
```

If you can't use JQuery in your project, see: [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_example_suggest.asp)